# Component dependency issue when upgrading Magento 2 from 2.0.7 to 2.1.0

Tags: magento2

I need to upgrade from magento 2 2.0.7 to 2.1.0. I tried by using composer  commands.

```
composer require magento/product-community-edition 2.1.0 --no-update

composer update
```

But I got an error like below:

> - Can only install one of: magento/framework[100.1.0, 100.0.9].
> - Can only install one of: magento/framework[100.1.0, 100.0.10].
> - magento/product-community-edition 2.1.0 requires magento/framework 100.1.0 -> satisfiable by magento/framework[100.1.0].
> - Installation request for magento/product-community-edition 2.1.0 -> satisfiable by magento/product-community-edition[2.1.0].

Could someone please give me some ideas?